# REGEX_String between strings in a list

Tags: python, regex, search, group

From this list:

```
['AUSTRALIA\nBELMONT PARK (WA', '\nR3\n1/5/4/2\n2/3/1/5\nEAGLE FARM (QLD']
```

I would like to reduce it to this list:

```
['BELMONT PARK', 'EAGLE FARM']
```

You can see from the first list that the desired words are between `'\n'` and `'('`.

My attempted solution is:

```
for i in x:
    result = re.search('\n(.*)(', i)
    print(result.group(1))
```

This returns the error 'unterminated subpattern'.
Thankyou

Comment: Escape the ( as [\\(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re getting an error because the `(` is unescaped. Regardless, it will not work, as you’ll get the following matches:

- `\nBELMONT PARK (`
- `\nR3\n1/5/4/2\n2/3/1/5\nEAGLE FARM (`

You can try the following:

```
(?<=\\n)(?!.*\\n)(.*)(?= \()
```

- `(?<=\\n)`: Positive lookbehind to ensure `\n` is before match
- `(?!.*\\n)`: Negative lookahead to ensure no further `\n` is included
- `(.*)`: Your match
- `(?= \()`: Positive lookahead to ensure  `(` is after match

Comment: Slight optimization- you can put the negative lookahead after the `.*` (and its positive lookahead) to avoid re-scanning that portion, since it won't match a newline anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matches without using any lookarounds, as you are already using a capture group.

```
\n(.*) \(
```

**Explanation**

- `\n` Match a newline
- `(.*)` Capture group 1, match any character except a newline, as much as possible
- `\(` Match a space and `(`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ef2e9l/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jccPKl).

**Example**

```
import re

x = ['AUSTRALIA\nBELMONT PARK (WA', '\nR3\n1/5/4/2\n2/3/1/5\nEAGLE FARM (QLD']
pattern = r"\n(.*) \("

for i in x:
    m = re.search(pattern, i)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
BELMONT PARK
EAGLE FARM
```

---

If you want to return a list:

```
x = ['AUSTRALIA\nBELMONT PARK (WA', '\nR3\n1/5/4/2\n2/3/1/5\nEAGLE FARM (QLD']
pattern = r"\n(.*) \("
res = [m.group(1) for i in x for m in [re.search(pattern, i)] if m]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['BELMONT PARK', 'EAGLE FARM']
```